My GTK application freezes when processing takes place
I have built an application in GTK, with buttons, that when pressed, they do something. The problem is that when a button is pressed and the related operation starts, the calculations start working, as I see in the Ubuntu terminal, but the widgets are freezed, they are not separateable, I cannot move them. When the calculations finish then the GTK widget is back and I can work with it. From google search I found "solutions" such as python thread level programming, pipes, multiprocessing, but I am not sure what to do. What I mean is that, if I change the whole rationale of my code into threads, which will take me about a month, by the way, does this solve my problem? Is there something faster I should do?
